# HTML page not fitting inside UIWebView - Need the entire HTML page to be contained inside the UIWebview so that no scrolling should be required

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

I have googled a lot and have found many solutions to my problem.. but none of them seem to work..

I am trying to load a responsive HTML page inside a `UIWebView`. However, the webpage is not displayed in its entirety. A user has to scroll left and right in order to view the entire content of the page.

I am using the following code:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]').setAttribute('content', 'width=%d;', false); ", (int)webView.frame.size.width]];
    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
  }
```

However, this fits the page width-wise only. A user still needs to scroll vertically to see the content. How to show the entire content within the space inside the `UIWebview`??
Is it possible that there may be a problem with the HTML page that i am loading??

Comment: What sort of behaviour would you expect to prevent vertical scrolling? For the page to be scaled vertically, or the text to be made smaller?

Comment: text to be made smaller preferably..

Comment: user should not need to scroll vertically or horizontally..

Comment: This is a tricky one. The first thought that occurs to me is that perhaps you could change `-webkit-text-size-adjust` on the document root (via JavaScript) to adjust the text size until it is small enough.

Comment: and how do i do that??

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in setting it in `-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`. so you can either set it in "webViewDidStartLoad"

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
}
```

or from the storyboard

[image]

Comment: I am not adding UIWebView through XIB. I am doing it programmatically. Setting the property in startLoad did not help either..

Comment: It worked correctly with some urls, while didn't work with others. I used this `NSString* js =
    @"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); "
    "meta.setAttribute( 'name', 'viewport' ); "
    "meta.setAttribute( 'content', 'width = %d' ); "
    "meta.setAttribute( 'content', 'height = %d' ); "
    "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta)";
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:js, (int)webView.frame.size.width,(int)webView.frame.size.height]];` with this page url, it sets the font size to the min,but still the page is scrolling.

Comment: So I think the answer is yes it's possible with some web pages, and not possible with the others.